# Could not find implicit when used in main method

Tags: scala, implicit

I've got code similar to the following extract:

```
object Obj {
  case class Dog(colour: String= "brown")

  def summon(dog: Dog = Dog()): Dog = dog

  def getColour(implicit d: Dog): String = d.colour

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val dog = summon(Dog(colour = "orange"))

    val colour = getColour
  }
}
```

This doesn't compile because the compiler can't find an implicit dog for parameter `d` when calling `getColour`. The strange thing though is that if I try to assign the result of `getColour` to a val named something other than `colour` it works. Also if I move the 2 lines out of the `main` method it works as well. Any ideas what's causing the implicit resolution to fail here?

I'm using Scala version 2.12.6.

Comment: Interesting! It works if you replace this line `implicit val dog = summon(Dog(colour = "orange"))` with this one `implicit val dog = summon(Dog("orange"))` .. Maybe you could file a bug report. :)

Comment: It also works with `colour` if you explicitly declare the type of `dog: Dog`. What!!!^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we remove `implicit` like so

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val dog = summon(Dog(colour = "orange"))
    val colour = getColour(dog) // error: recursive value dog needs type
  }
```

we get `recursive value dog needs type`, so I believe this is an instance of

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5091

Comment: Makes sense. The unresolved implicit seem to have hidden the underlying issue. And there's an open ticket for sbt (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1928) which apparently hides the warning messages added as part of SI-5091.